# Can one, under any condition, shower using hot water on the Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, showering-bathing

Is there any situation, **bar imminent threat of death**, which would allow one to shower with hot water during the Shabbat, using hot water which is heated *on* the Shabbat, or is it absolutely not allowed?

Comment: http://matzav.com/taking-a-shower-on-shabbos

Comment: How about a possible threat of death? (As opposed to an imminent one)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.nishmat.net/Uploads/files/Ask-Rav-Sperling-Washing-on-Shabbat-and-YT.pdf) seems to provide a detailed analysis of this question. Excerpt from beginning. (Read the rest of the article as well as cited sources, there):

> SUMMARY – on Shabbat one may wash up to half their body in permitted
>   hot water. The types of hot water that is considered permitted to
>   (partially) wash with on Shabbat are, water heated before Shabbat that
>   can be used without causing new cold water to cook; or water that was
>   heated on Shabbat by itself, which includes water from the solar water
>   unit (according to those who rule that solar water heaters are
>   permitted on Shabbat); and possibly water heated up by a non-Jew for
>   his own use. There is a debate about how cold water must be to still
>   be considered "cold" water.

Comment: My son-in-law came to visit me in the hospital twice on a Shabbos.  It was hot and he got pretty smelly.  Rabbi Dovid Rosenbaum told him he could take a cold shower to clean up before coming to shul for Mincha.

Comment: Why are we be able to use water from the sink if it comes from the same hot water heater that supplies water to the shower. I live in apartment so tell me if I am wrong about that. I once asked a rabbi if a water fountain could be used on שבת and he said yes even though it was powered by electricity.

Comment: @JJLL Who said you can use hot water from a sink on Shabbat?

Comment: @JJLL the taking of water which allows more water into a device which uses a thermostat to turn on and off is a grama, indirect action. We are especially meikel if this gramma only effects electricity. Therefore a water cooler is allowed to be used. Turning on the hot tap allows cold water into a boiling hot tank is a problem in and of itself. The action which may be caused through the gramma is real fire. We are therefore machmir. If you would take me up on my offer to learn together we can go through hilchos shabbos:) no pressure, but Im still waiting.

Comment: Thank you @user6591 I promise to take you up on your offer. And thank you for your response.

Comment: @user6591 Grama? Meikel? Machmir? Milchos shabbos? What do these words mean in the context of this question?

Comment: @Daft Which part needs clarification? The translation or application?

Comment: @user6591 first one and then the other I suppose. I'm unclear on both. Feel free to post it as an answer, as it will clarify my understanding of the situation.

Comment: Grama=indirect cause. A general idea found throughout the Talmud with various applications. Meikel=lenient. Machmir=stringent. Melachos shabbos= the actions the Torah and Rabbis forbade to do on shabbos. The laws of shabbos both biblical and rabbinic are very intricate. There are other questions on this site and all over the web to become more familiar with them. Concerning my comment to JJLL, the use of electricity is mostly accepted to be of rabbinic origin in most situations in modern day life. Boilers and water heaters work with real fire which in many situations is biblical.

Comment: Many rabbits are lenient concerning a water cooler. Whereas with a boiler they are stringent, due to fact that we would be playing with fire. Literally:) This is all besides various rabbinic enactments from the Talmudic Times against bathing with hot water.